# Phantom wallet error - Transaction expired

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, phantom, react, phantom-wallet

I'm trying to submit a transaction on my app, which works with different wallets such as Solflare, but if I try to use Phantom I always get the error message:

> You waited too long to approve the transaction and it expired. This transaction will revert if submitted.

I have no idea why this happens and it never happens with a different wallet. I'm not waiting at all, this message appears after about 1 second after trying to submit a transaction.

I am using the newest versions of `@solana-wallet-adapter` packages as of this date. My transaction submitting code is the same as in the example here: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md.

[image: Phantom error]

Comment: Hi! Can you confirm if your wallet is set to the same network that your transaction is on? For example, if the transaction you're signing is on devnet then your wallet should be set to devnet as well. (Developer Settings -> Change Network)

Comment: Hi, it was not set to the same network and that did actually fix it, as the app was on devnet. I didn't realize I needed to do that, as it wasn't necessary when I used a different wallet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error most commonly results from a network mismatch between the wallet and the dapp. For instance, if you are developing a dapp on devnet, Phantom will also need to be set to devnet. If it is set to a different network, it will be unable to recognize the devnet blockhash provided from the dapp. Because Solana blockhashes expire after 150 blocks, Phantom will assume it is simply an old blockhash and will instantly show this warning. We're working on an improvement to this error message and the network mismatch experience.

Comment: Is this still being worked on? It's been a while :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the app was set to use devnet, and Phantom wasn't. I needed to change the network connection within Phantom's settings (Developer Settings -> Change Network).

Thanks to Brian for pointing that out in the comments.